# Pandoc: Markdown to Tex -- with using filter show error "failed to parse field blocks"

Tags: python, pandoc

I try adapt this [pandoc filter](https://github.com/jgm/pandocfilters/blob/master/examples/theorem.py) but I need use Span instead Div.

input file (myfile.md):

```
### MY HEADER

[File > Open]{.menu}

[\ctrl + C]{.keys}

Simply line
```

filter file (myfilter.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from pandocfilters import *

def latex(x):
    return RawBlock('latex', x)


def latex_menukeys(key, value, format, meta):
    if key == 'Span':
    [[ident, classes, kvs], contents] = value

    if classes[0] == "menu":
        return([latex('\\menu{')] + contents + [latex('}')])
    elif classes[0] == "keys":
        return([latex('\\keys{')] + contents + [latex('}')])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    toJSONFilter(latex_menukeys)
```

run:

```
pandoc myfile.md -o myfile.tex -F myfilter.py

pandoc:Error in $.blocks[1].c[0]: failed to parse field blocks: failed to parse field c: mempty 
CallStack <fromHasCallStack>: 
error, called at pandoc.hs:144:42 in main:Main
```

How I should use varyable "contents" correct?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `Span` is inside a paragraph. Then you would be trying to replace it with a `RawBlock`, which is not going to work. Maybe try using `RawInline` instead?